# How to allow users to change my Accurev stream

Tags: accurev

I'm going to be on vacations for a month, the stream needs to be supported. How to allow other users to change my Accurev stream (change time label, backed stream, etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default anyone can change the time basis, rename a stream, apply locks, etc..to streams.  The only way to prevent these operations from occurring is thorough the server_admin_trig.  If you have enabled this trigger to block users from performing these acts, then I suggest you create a group, add whoever needs to admin this stream for you and update the script to allow this group to perform those operations.